# How to add a member to an existing Outlook Distribution List?

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

I am trying to add a member to an existing Outlook distribution list using Python library win32com.

I do not have any trouble deleting an existing member with the following code:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

myDistributionList = outlook.Folders.Item(1).Folders[5].Items.Item('DL') # Number 5 because the DL is in the contacts folder

firstContact = myDistributionList.GetMember(1)

myDistributionList.RemoveMember(firstContact)

myDistributionList.Save()
```

Reading VBA documentation, I learnt that to use the method AddMember of a distribution list I must create a recipient object. Even so the following code does not give any error, it seems as it does not run. The DL in Outlook is still empty.

```
newContact = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").Session.CreateRecipient('example@gmail.com')

myDistributionList.AddMember(newContact)

myDistributionList.Save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*ANSWER*

Okay, I have solved my own question. I do not know if it is the most efficient way but it runs.

I had to create two different items. A mail item and a contact item. Then I assigned an address to the contact item and that address was passed to the mail item's property called recipients. Lastly I passed this recipient to the DL.

```
myTempItem  = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0) # Mail item

contact = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(2) # Contact item

contact.Email1Address = 'example@gmail.com'

myTempItem.Recipients.Add(contact.Email1Address)

myDistributionList.AddMembers(myTempItem.Recipients)

myDistributionList.Save()

# And if you want to see the contact group
myDistributionList.Display()
```